Problem with master/slave IoT Edge topology (certificates and configuration)
I'm trying to configure a pair of master/slave IoT Edge nodes running on top of 2 Raspberry Pi using Debian 11 armhf (32 bits) but I can't get it working because of a certificate problem (that's for sure) and there could be a configuration problem as well (that's something I need to confirm).
What I've done so far in the master node is:

Set the master's hostname as iot-edge-gateway.local in /etc/hostname and update /etc/hosts to resolve this name to the static IP address of the node (in a local network).
Configure the IoT Edge with iotedge config mp --connection-string 'CONNECTION STRING'. When I execute this command, I receive a warning indicating this configuration is not valid for gateways, but I guess that's normal since some additional fields need to be added to the configuration file.
Create the certificates using the certGen.sh with:

./certGen.sh create_root_and_intermediate

./certGen.sh create_edge_device_identity_certificate "my-edge-device-1"

./certGen.sh create_edge_device_ca_certificate "root"


Move all the files to the right location (/var/aziot/certs and /var/aziot/secrets) and configured the permissions.
Updated /etc/aziot/config.toml to incorporate the missing properties:

auto_reprovisioning_mode = "OnErrorOnly"
prefer_module_identity_cache = false

trust_bundle_cert = "file:///var/aziot/certs/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem"

[edge_ca]
cert = "file:///var/aziot/certs/iot-edge-device-ca-root.cert.pem"

pk = "file:///var/aziot/secrets/iot-edge-device-identity-my-edge-device-1.key.pem"

[provisioning]
source = "manual"
connection_string = "HostName=XXXX;DeviceId=my-edge-device-1;SharedAccessKey=XXXX"

[aziot_keys]

[preloaded_keys]

[cert_issuance]

[preloaded_certs]

[tpm]

[agent]
name = "edgeAgent"
type = "docker"
imagePullPolicy = "on-create"

[agent.config]
image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.5"

[agent.config.createOptions]

[agent.env]

[connect]
workload_uri = "unix:///var/run/iotedge/workload.sock"
management_uri = "unix:///var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock"

[listen]
workload_uri = "fd://aziot-edged.workload.socket"
management_uri = "fd://aziot-edged.mgmt.socket"

[watchdog]
max_retries = "infinite"

[moby_runtime]
uri = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
network = "azure-iot-edge"


Restarted the whole system (including recreating the containers) with:

iotedge system stop && docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq -f "label=net.azure-devices.edge.owner=Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent") && iotedge config apply

With this, both edgeHub and edgeAgent start correctly as you can see here:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                      COMMAND                   CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                                                   NAMES
9cc2e76a01c4   mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.5     "/bin/sh -c 'echo \"$…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5671->5671/tcp, :::5671->5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8883->8883/tcp, :::8883->8883/tcp, 1883/tcp   edgeHub
83c870270863   mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.5   "/bin/sh -c 'exec /a…"    17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes                                                                                                                                           edgeAgent

In the slave side, what I do is extend the connection string to include the GatewayHostName attribute and I include the parent_hostname attribute as well. As a result, I have this:
auto_reprovisioning_mode = "OnErrorOnly"
prefer_module_identity_cache = false

parent_hostname = "iot-edge-gateway.local"

[provisioning]
source = "manual"
connection_string = "HostName=YYYY;DeviceId=my-edge-device-2;SharedAccessKey=YYYY;GatewayHostName=iot-edge-gateway.local"

[aziot_keys]

[preloaded_keys]

[cert_issuance]

[preloaded_certs]

[tpm]

[agent]
name = "edgeAgent"
type = "docker"
imagePullPolicy = "on-create"

[agent.config]
image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.5"

[agent.config.createOptions]

[agent.env]

[connect]
workload_uri = "unix:///var/run/iotedge/workload.sock"
management_uri = "unix:///var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock"

[listen]
workload_uri = "fd://aziot-edged.workload.socket"
management_uri = "fd://aziot-edged.mgmt.socket"

[watchdog]
max_retries = "infinite"

[moby_runtime]
uri = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
network = "azure-iot-edge"

Obviously, I've added an entry to /etc/hosts to make sure this hostname can be resolved. With this, I've confirmed that the slave is trying to communicate with the master, and here is where I've found a problem with the certificates.
What I've done is (these are the steps documented in the portal, one by one):

Copy the CA certificate to the default CA location of the slave:

sudo cp azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem.crt

sudo update-ca-certificates


1 certificate has been added as expected.
However, although the slave really tries to establish the connection with the master (it bypasses the master if you don't include the parent_hostname attribute in /etc/aziot/config.toml even if you extend the connection string and include GatewayHostName), that's something I've confirmed with tcpdump, there's a problem with the signature.
The way to test whether the certificate is valid or not is also documented:
openssl s_client -connect iot-edge-gateway.local:8883 -CAfile ./azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem -showcerts

And the output is here:
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 CN = root.ca
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = iot-edge-gateway.local
verify error:num=7:certificate signature failure
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = iot-edge-gateway.local
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = iot-edge-gateway.local
   i:CN = root.ca
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:CN = root.ca
   i:CN = Azure_IoT_Hub_Intermediate_Cert_Test_Only
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=CN = iot-edge-gateway.local

issuer=CN = root.ca

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2826 bytes and written 424 bytes
Verification error: certificate signature failure
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 83ECFFFCF6D6DDB25C514346C3FE04738B6C9D71028CE1040309FDFD43825C42
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: 340BAF166C555E9441C0A46EAE88B4908C78BC3C3BA9BAA407AFA22A23B8E15A2DEB5EA5ED9FB52B1BB2DDB7D50A3113
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 04 25 ab 77 b5 0f e8 74-74 7e ec cd ae 07 6b 2b   .%.w...tt~....k+
    0010 - 75 20 72 94 44 1b d4 59-ae 2e 0a aa 00 d4 98 f5   u r.D..Y........
    0020 - c1 0c ed a8 e0 ab f0 11-d3 7b a6 f4 60 2a 67 38   .........{..`*g8
    0030 - 3d e3 85 16 06 00 be 77-15 cb 13 9e 5c 07 96 d7   =......w....\...
    0040 - f0 73 4b 94 5f b9 9a 19-32 bc e5 69 1d a5 cd f1   .sK._...2..i....
    0050 - 2e f8 6a d6 20 64 07 09-d0 db 78 30 88 96 31 55   ..j. d....x0..1U
    0060 - b3 5d a1 67 3a 3a ab 8e-ac c3 69 08 d3 cb 64 96   .].g::....i...d.
    0070 - db e7 10 37 d6 c7 8e 66-b5 12 97 60 22 85 13 d1   ...7...f...`"...
    0080 - c9 eb d5 a2 12 d3 b3 f0-3a 62 68 cf ce 7a 9a d8   ........:bh..z..
    0090 - 37 c9 02 cd f4 d7 6d 2c-d8 95 64 15 e2 4e 4c 77   7.....m,..d..NLw
    00a0 - c1 4a 6f 1d 41 c7 f9 77-af 57 ff 3c d0 a2 72 7b   .Jo.A..w.W.<..r{
    00b0 - 00 ad 3b 5a c0 5e d6 34-fd eb 8e 12 61 c9 ad 9d   ..;Z.^.4....a...
    00c0 - c0 3b 7d f7 ae 2f 7f 59-d5 5b 03 64 a7 0d c3 28   .;}../.Y.[.d...(
    00d0 - dd c0 ac 77 b8 46 7a 8d-c2 df bd 58 10 6e b3 eb   ...w.Fz....X.n..
    00e0 - 0e 65 7e dc a2 16 80 f7-2b f8 cf f9 2f 7a 25 d4   .e~.....+.../z%.

    Start Time: 1715181617
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: A17E3D3E3082AD3929994E395E55C366A347E702573CDD694E23AB60B4F68BA0
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: 9140F930B31CA9416C462E6077B43FE38BC8490BCB50E024B0519E67B8F82082F904A52ABC0C5B9160EC8A4410B529DA
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 04 25 ab 77 b5 0f e8 74-74 7e ec cd ae 07 6b 2b   .%.w...tt~....k+
    0010 - ff da 60 3b 06 23 c6 60-c5 34 b7 70 49 b5 61 05   ..`;.#.`.4.pI.a.
    0020 - 2a 13 38 6c bd c1 b6 af-a8 34 7a ba 0f 83 42 a2   *.8l.....4z...B.
    0030 - d5 df 1e 76 0e 44 be 64-a2 17 1f 1e 98 79 05 ed   ...v.D.d.....y..
    0040 - 0a 95 21 e0 82 58 b6 6b-bb 8c 6f db 7c f9 0b 60   ..!..X.k..o.|..`
    0050 - 23 82 e3 51 5b 2e be 9b-8c 73 ac ea e6 52 32 84   #..Q[....s...R2.
    0060 - 63 e0 2b 2e 30 05 e6 ef-c9 c1 90 32 d1 28 62 5b   c.+.0......2.(b[
    0070 - f5 0d 7f 64 13 27 8a b4-9f 95 72 f4 08 fe 66 0d   ...d.'....r...f.
    0080 - 10 e9 df 8d ea 8b 72 aa-9e 73 f8 a7 b3 3e 31 78   ......r..s...>1x
    0090 - 97 66 91 03 33 94 35 b2-03 d1 a1 60 dd bc 43 87   .f..3.5....`..C.
    00a0 - 8b dd ad f6 4c 05 43 33-a7 b3 c3 5a 71 55 e2 a0   ....L.C3...ZqU..
    00b0 - fe 08 bb e4 36 7b 40 67-1d 3a 65 6a 6c 0a 52 67   ....6{@g.:ejl.Rg
    00c0 - 1e e6 c1 dd ae 39 23 7d-36 1d 51 03 58 7a 6e f0   .....9#}6.Q.Xzn.
    00d0 - 41 92 a0 a3 59 b3 05 0b-b9 b3 fe 63 7f d4 0b 3d   A...Y......c...=
    00e0 - 85 ed 67 70 80 77 e8 eb-92 07 22 5f d3 e1 fe d6   ..gp.w...."_....

    Start Time: 1715181617
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK

As you can see, there's a problem with the signature. And my questions are:

Have I configured properly both master and slave to work together?
Is there any problem with the CA name used in ./certGen.sh create_edge_device_ca_certificate "root"? I don't know if I can use any name or if the name must be referenced in any config file.

What I don't understand is why this is failing considering I've followed the documentation step by step.
==============================================================
UPDATE 1:
I've tried to fix the chained-validation of certificate problem described by @Architect Jamie with no success.
If I had to guess, the problem has to do with either the order of the certificates in the pem files or the certificates configured in /etc/aziot/config.toml for trust_bundle_cert, and cert and pk inside [edge_ca].
What I've tried:
trust_bundle_cert = "file:///var/aziot/certs/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem"

cert = "file:///var/aziot/certs/iot-edge-device-ca-root.cert.pem"
pk = "file:///var/aziot/secrets/iot-edge-device-ca-root.key.pem"

And:
openssl s_client -connect iot-edge-gateway.local:8883 -CAfile ./azure-iot-test-only.intermediate-full-chain.cert.pem -showcerts

This way the SSL connection works fine. This certificate file includes 2 certificates:

Intermediate certificate.
Root CA.

However, when I copy azure-iot-test-only.intermediate-full-chain.cert.pem to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/azure-iot-test-only.intermediate-full-chain.cert.pem.crt and run sudo update-ca-certificates, I get:
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
rehash: warning: skipping azure-iot-test-only.intermediate-full-chain.cert.pem.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.

And in /etc/ssl/certs I have:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   89 May  9 18:44 azure-iot-test-only.intermediate-full-chain.cert.pem.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/azure-iot-test-only.intermediate-full-chain.cert.pem.crt

If I copy the root CA and not the intermediate-full-chain, in addition to a link equivalent to the previous one, another one with a bunch of characters is created (looks like some sort of MD5/SHA, something like b66938e9.0).
Although the direct connection using openssl works, when I launch the services and the slave tries to connect with the master I get this from journalctl -xe:
May 09 18:56:56 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:56Z [INFO] - <-- PUT /identities/modules/$edgeAgent?api-version=2020-09-01&type=aziot {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "identityd.sock", "content-length": "40"}
May 09 18:56:56 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[4934]: 2024-05-09T16:56:56Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
May 09 18:56:56 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[4934]: 2024-05-09T16:56:56Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 09 18:56:56 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[4934]: 2024-05-09T16:56:56Z [INFO] - <-- POST /sign?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "386"}
May 09 18:56:56 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[4934]: 2024-05-09T16:56:56Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 09 18:56:56 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:56Z [WARN] - Failed to send HTTP request (attempt 1 of 2): error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:: unable to get local issuer certificate
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:59Z [WARN] - Failed to send HTTP request (attempt 2 of 2): error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:: unable to get local issuer certificate
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:59Z [INFO] - !!! Hub client error
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:59Z [INFO] - !!! caused by: error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:: unable to get local issuer certificate
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:59Z [INFO] - !!! caused by: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:: unable to get local issuer certificate
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:59Z [INFO] - !!! caused by: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:59Z [INFO] - !!! caused by: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[4929]: 2024-05-09T16:56:59Z [INFO] - --> 404 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-edged[4924]: 2024-05-09T16:56:59Z [WARN] - Error in watchdog: Failed to update $edgeAgent identity: Hub client error
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-edged[4924]: caused by: error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:: unable to get local issuer certificate
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-edged[4924]: caused by: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:: unable to get local issuer certificate
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-edged[4924]: caused by: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:
May 09 18:56:59 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-edged[4924]: caused by: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:
May 09 18:57:03 iot-edge-slave.local defender_iot_micro_agent[405]: Error: Time:Thu May  9 18:51:58 2024 File:/__w/1/s/deps/azure-iot-sdk-c/c-utility/adapters/tlsio_openssl.c Func:send_handshake_bytes Line:734 error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
May 09 18:57:03 iot-edge-slave.local defender_iot_micro_agent[405]: Error: Time:Thu May  9 18:51:58 2024 File:/__w/1/s/deps/azure-iot-sdk-c/umqtt/src/mqtt_client.c Func:onOpenComplete Line:452 Error: failure opening connection to endpoint

So, do I need to create the MD5-like link manually? I've read somewhere that's caused by a problem of update-ca-certificates but apparently it should work since a link is created in /etc/ssl/certs. I guess my first attempt was wrong because I was including the device id certificate instead of the device ca certificate in /etc/aziot/config.toml but now that's been fixed.
==============================================================
UPDATE 2:
Ok, the certificate problem was fixed by loading the 3 separate (individual) certificates in the slave. With this now I have this content in /etc/ssl/certs:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40 May 10 09:29 05c5438d.0 -> azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   45 May 10 09:50 2a3cc244.0 -> azure-iot-test-only.intermediate.cert.pem.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 May 10 09:50 5a615dc3.0 -> iot-edge-device-ca-root.cert.pem.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   78 May 10 09:50 azure-iot-test-only.intermediate.cert.pem.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/azure-iot-test-only.intermediate.cert.pem.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   73 May 10 09:29 azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   69 May 10 09:50 iot-edge-device-ca-root.cert.pem.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/iot-edge-device-ca-root.cert.pem.crt

As I expected, these link names (05c5438d.0, 2a3cc244.0 and 5a615dc3.0) are generated by either openssl rehash o directly by c_rehash and only appear if the certificate files contain 1 certificate. I don't know if this hash is directly related to the CN of the certificate or to the whole file, but that's how it works.
With this, I can try the openssl client example using -CApath instead of -CAfile (this way it uses the 3 individual certificates properly):
openssl s_client -connect iot-edge-gateway.local:8883 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -showcerts

This works fine and the SSL connection can be established from the slave to the master properly.
However, there seems to be a problem with the provisioning. I don't know if there's some misconfiguration in the master node or in the slave, but the slave can't reach the IoT Hub.
In the slave, my /etc/aziot/config.toml is:
auto_reprovisioning_mode = "OnErrorOnly"
prefer_module_identity_cache = false

parent_hostname = "iot-edge-gateway.local"

[provisioning]
source = "manual"
connection_string = "HostName=XXXX;DeviceId=my-edge-device-2;SharedAccessKey=YYYY;GatewayHostName=iot-edge-gateway.local"

[aziot_keys]

[preloaded_keys]

[cert_issuance]

[preloaded_certs]

[tpm]

[agent]
name = "edgeAgent"
type = "docker"
imagePullPolicy = "on-create"

[agent.config]
image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.5"

[agent.config.createOptions]

[agent.env]

[connect]
workload_uri = "unix:///var/run/iotedge/workload.sock"
management_uri = "unix:///var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock"

[listen]
workload_uri = "fd://aziot-edged.workload.socket"
management_uri = "fd://aziot-edged.mgmt.socket"

[watchdog]
max_retries = "infinite"

[moby_runtime]
uri = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
network = "azure-iot-edge"

With this, after applying the configuration, this is the content of /etc/aziot/identityd/config.d/00-super.toml
# This file is auto-generated by `iotedge config apply`
# Do not edit it manually; any edits will be lost when the command is run again.

hostname = "iot-edge-slave.local"
homedir = "/var/lib/aziot/identityd"
prefer_module_identity_cache = false

[provisioning]
local_gateway_hostname = "iot-edge-gateway.local"
source = "manual"
iothub_hostname = "XXXX"
device_id = "my-edge-device-2"

[provisioning.authentication]
method = "sas"
device_id_pk = "device-id"

[[principal]]
uid = 994
name = "aziot-edge"

And the output of journalctl -xe is:
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - Starting service...
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - Version - 1.5.0
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - Loaded libaziot-keys with version 0x02010000
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - Starting server...
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /sign?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "386>
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /sign?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "386>
May 10 10:29:05 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[15481]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - Could not reconcile Identities with current device data. Reprovisioning.
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[15481]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - Updated device info for my-edge-device-2.
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - <-- POST /sign?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "386>
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - <-- POST /sign?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "386>
May 10 10:29:06 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-keyd[15486]: 2024-05-10T08:29:06Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
May 10 10:29:07 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[15481]: 2024-05-10T08:29:07Z [ERR!] - Failed to provision with IoT Hub, and no valid device backup was found: Hub client error
May 10 10:29:07 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[15481]: 2024-05-10T08:29:07Z [ERR!] - service encountered an error
May 10 10:29:07 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[15481]: 2024-05-10T08:29:07Z [ERR!] - caused by: Hub client error
May 10 10:29:07 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[15481]: 2024-05-10T08:29:07Z [ERR!] - caused by: invalid HTTP status code
May 10 10:29:07 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[15481]: 2024-05-10T08:29:07Z [ERR!] -    0: <unknown>
May 10 10:29:07 iot-edge-slave.local aziot-identityd[15481]:    1: <unknown>

The configuration of the paths in the master includes 2 (as extracted from the documentation):

NAME: allMessagesToHub
VALUE: FROM /messages/* INTO $upstream

NAME: allDownstreamToHub
VALUE: FROM /messages/* WHERE NOT IS_DEFINED ($connectionModuleId) INTO $upstream


Regards

The issue you're having is that the slave is not able to verify the signature of the device certificate because the issuer is the intermediate CA, not the root CA.
The client must be able to verify a complete chain back to the trusted root. You added the root CA, but not the intermediate.
To resolve, you should import the intermediate public cert on the slave.
You could also add the intermediate cert to the device cert instead, which will allow chained cryptographic verification back to the root CA. You just add the contents of the intermediate PEM to the end of the device PEM. As long as the client can see that your imported root CA signed the intermediate, and the intermediate signed the device, then this will pass X509 verification.

That's pretty much what I've done based on UPDATE 1, and although the direct openssl connection works fine now, I still receive an "unable to get local issuer certificate" error based on the output of "journalctl -xe".

Oh, in that case you need to add the root and intermediate CAs on the slave node, too. @user3214726

Ok, certificate problem solved by adding the 3 CAs (root, intermediate and device) separately as indicated in UPDATE 2. With this, SSL is ok but now I don't understand why the slave can't reach the IoT Hub through the master since this is the whole purpose of using this topology..

It's not clear to me if this:
[edge_ca]
cert = "file:///var/aziot/certs/iot-edge-device-ca-root.cert.pem"
references a full chain in the parent config.toml. If not, then it needs to. The order is significant too. It must start with the lowest certificate and end with the highest.
